# activeStyle does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: typescript, react-router-dom

I am trying to use NavLink in react typescript project, however, it's getting an error.
Property 'activeStyle' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & NavLinkProps & RefAttributes'.

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Nav () {
  return (
        <nav className='row space-between'>
          <ul className='row nav'>
            <li>
              <NavLink
                to='/'
                activeStyle={{
                  textDecoration: 'none',
                  color: 'red'
                }}
                className='nav-link'>
                Top
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <NavLink
                to='/new'
                className='nav-link'>
                New
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
          
        </nav>
  )
}
```

Comment: Are you using `v6`? `activeStyle` was proposed to be removed from `v6`.

Comment: Yes using v6, what is the alternative option there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`activeStyle` is deprecated in v6. You can use `style` function like this:

```
<NavLink
 to='/'
 className='nav-link'
 style={
  ({isActive}) => (
   isActive 
   ? {
      textDecoration: 'none',
      color: 'red'
     }
   :{}
   )
 }
>
Top
</NavLink>
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-example-forked-68cxe?file=/src/App.js:1224-1555)

Answer (score 3):

The `NavLink` API changed a bit in RRDv6, there is no longer an `activeStyle` prop.

[NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink)

> ```
> interface NavLinkProps
>   extends Omit<LinkProps, "className" | "style"> {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   className?:
>     | string
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => string);
>   end?: boolean;
>   style?:
>     | React.CSSProperties
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => React.CSSProperties);
> }
> ```

You can conditionally apply your active class via a `style` or `className` prop function. Using the style prop.

```
const isActiveStyle = {
  textDecoration: 'none',
  color: 'red'
};
```

...

```
<NavLink
  style={({ isActive }) => isActive ? isActiveStyle : {}}
  to="/"
>
  Top
</NavLink>
```